# Is there any difference between the following two code snippets?

Tags: ruby

The following two code snippets should be same but they return different outputs

```
movies = {
  StarWars: 4.8, 
  Divergent: 4.7
  }

puts "What would you like to do? "

choice = gets.chomp

case choice
when "add"
  puts "What movie would you like to add? "
  title = gets.chomp
  if movies[title.to_sym] = nil
    puts "What rating does the movie have? "
    rating = gets.chomp
    movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
    puts "#{title} has been added"
  else
    puts "That movie already exists! Its rating is #{movies[title.to_sym]}."
  end
```

```
movies = {
  StarWars: 4.8, 
  Divergent: 4.7
  }

puts "What would you like to do? "

choice = gets.chomp

case choice
when "add"
  puts "What movie would you like to add? "
  title = gets.chomp
  if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
    puts "What rating does the movie have? "
    rating = gets.chomp
    movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
    puts "#{title} has been added"
  else
    puts "That movie already exists! Its rating is #{movies[title.to_sym]}."
  end
```

**OUTPUT 1:**
What would you like to do? 
add
What movie would you like to add? 
StarWars
That movie already exists! Its rating is .

**OUTPUT 2:** 
What would you like to do? 
add
What movie would you like to add? 
StarWars
That movie already exists! Its rating is 4.8.

PS: I didn't paste the rest of the code as it would be irrelevant

Comment: Output of `diff` on your two files: https://pastebin.com/XBEKSzzM. In the future, please try simple things like this on your own before using StackOverflow as a command line service.

Comment: `if movies[title.to_sym] = nil` is an assignment statement, not a comparison statement.

Comment: Are you asking what's the difference between `if movies[title.to_sym] = nil` and `if movies[title.to_sym].nil?`?

Comment: To expand on @ggorlen's answer, an assignment statement will return the value that was assigned to the variable, in this case `nil`, which is falsey, whereas `movies[title.to_sym].nil?` evaluates to `true`

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't double check whether I used = or ==

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I'd like to know why it still gives an output though, shouldn't it give me a syntax error or nothing at all?

Comment: Then ggorlen has your answer. You're *assigning* `nil` to the field, and when interpolated `nil` prints as `""`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo thanks, I get it

Comment: Your question is unclear. You ask whether there is any difference between those two code snippets, and then you immediately state that they produce different outputs. So, obviously, there *is* a difference, and thus your question is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the files comes down to these two lines:

```
if movies[title.to_sym] = nil
```

and

```
if movies[title.to_sym].nil?
```

The first is an assignment statement while the second tests whether the value fetched from the `movies` hash is `nil`.

The problem is that the result of the assignment statement is evaluated conditionally as a falsey bool: the `moves[title.to_sym]` value is set to `nil`, then the conditional amounts to `if nil`.

Pop quiz. What is the output of the following program and why?

```
h = {a: 42}

p "one" if h[:a] == 42
p "two" if h[:a] == nil
p "three" if h[:a] = 42
p "four" if h[:a] = nil
```

Answer:

> "one" "three" (the first conditional is a typical comparison that succeeds; the second is a typical comparison that fails; the third is an assignment that returns a truthy value, 42; the fourth is an assignment that returns a falsey value, nil)

---

Although controversial, [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) solve this accidental assignment bug:

```
p "yoda assignment" if nil = 42
```

Output:

```
(repl):1: Can't assign to nil
p "yoda assignment" if nil = 42
```

Comment: I'm actually a bit surprised you *can't* assign to `nil` in Ruby. You can definitely name a method `nil`, at least.

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but this is unsurprising about the method naming.